# About assembly language condition choosing

Tags: assembly

I'm more familiar with c language, but how do we write the below c language coding to assembly language? I've tried but always failed.

```
if(a==4)
{
   routine1();
}
else if(a==5)
{
    routine2();
}
else if(a==6)
{
    routine3();
}
```

Comment: Which assembly language?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to rewrite it using `goto`, then it should be straight-forward to port to whatever asm language you use.

```
if (a != 4) goto not4;
routine1();
goto end;

not4: if (a != 5) goto not5;
routine2();
goto end;

not5: if (a != 6) goto not6;
routine3();
end:
```

Answer (score 0):

In x86 it would be something like this also check out the link for in depth description of commands  http://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_instruction_set.pdf

```
a100 
mov al, 0500;move whats in memory location 0500 to al register
mov bl,4; mov 4 into bl register
cmp al,bl;this compares them basically subtracting them so 0 is equal
jz label1;the label is another memory location that you would jump to if they are equal
mov bl,5; if it doesnt jump then the code will continue to run
cmp al,bl
jz label2
mov bl,6
cmp al,bl
jz label3
int 3; to end program or you can use ret
```

...

```
label1 call 0200;call instruction runs the code that is at the memory location stated
label2 call 0300
label3 call 0400
```

hopefully this helps and remember this is x86!!
Happy Coding!!